# A Strange but seemingly easy functional equation problem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, functional-equations

I was solving a much larger problem and hence reduced it to a functional equation which looks a little strange but also seems easy to solve.

Question : Find all differentiable functions f defined on entire reals and differentiable on reals such that is satisfies the following

$$ f(2n) -f(-2n) = f'(2n) - f'(-2n) +4n^2 $$

for natural numbers n.

I need some help to solve this out so if anyone can help it will be appreciated and helpful.

Comment: Rename $2n=x$, so
$f(x)-f(-x)= 2f'(x)-2f'(-x)+x^2$
and then $f(x)-f(-x)=2g(x)$ such that $2g(x)=4g'(x)+x^2$
which is solved by $g(x)=x^2/2+2x+4+ce^{x/2}$.
Since $g(x)=[f(x)-f(-x)]/2= -g(-x)$ is the odd part of $f(x)$, and $G(x)=[f(x)+f(-x)]/2=G(-x)$
the even part, $f(x)=g(x)+G(x)$,  there is the contradiction that neither $x^2/2$ nor $e^{x/2}$
are odd functions. So apparently no such functions exist.

Comment: Can be an answer. as well.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar . Consider the function f(x) = x^/2 when x > 0 and -x^2/2 when x is negetive. This function satisfies the the equation

Comment: There was a trivial sign error in my comment (which apparently cannot be edited): of course $f(x)-f(-x)=2f'(x)+2f'(-x)+x^2$, so the entire rest of splitting into even and odd components is wrong.